# Google Colab - connecting to Google Cloud Storage does not create an adc.json file since few days

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, tpu

For the recent few days I have been struggling with the following problem on Google Colab
[image]
Upon entering the produced link and entering my credentials the usual text to copy is not there.
Instead I get this window[image]

Afterwards the connection to the google cloud storage looks like this [image]. The project number 522309567947 is not my project and I do not understand why its appearing there.

After entering my project ID I am able to connect to my google cloud storage account but the adc.json file with client_id, client_secret and refresh token is not produced. I need this file to connect my tensorflow to my google cloud storage.

The following code will create an error because the adc.json does not exist.

[image]

Is there any solution to my problem? Or any workaround to get the adc.json file?

Answer (score 1):

The following code, should fix the issue you see:

!gcloud auth application-default login  --no-launch-browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The real hint is the project number 522309567947, which is probably the project number for the project Collab is hosted in. This means that it's not an authentication issue but a client project id or quota project id configuration issue.

Setting your quota project would probably resolve the issue:

```
!gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project your-project-id
```

The solution for me was to explicitly set the quota project id when creating the client:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

options = ClientOptions(quota_project_id="your-project-id")
transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient(client_options=options)

parent = transfer_client.common_location_path(project=project, location="europe")

configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)
print("Got the following configs:")
for config in configs:
    print(f"\tID: {config.name}, Schedule: {config.schedule}")
```